# Update SQL Server Management Studio without restart

Tags: sql-server, ssms, upgrade

When I install or update SQL Server Management Studio it always asks to restart the server. Like now when I updated from 17.3 to 17.4, it asks to restart the server when the update is finished. Is it possible to avoid that somehow?

I now I should not have SSMS on the SQL Server itself, but we still do that, so it is annoying that you have to restart the db server just for updating the client.

Comment: I thought this question was relevant to most MSSQL DBAs, since SSMS asks if you want to install an update when one comes available. And if it is not possible to do it without a restart I guess most DBAs would say no to that question on a production server and wait for a maintenance window.

Answer (score 2):

Reference:

- [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

**Minimize Installation Reboots**

Take the following actions to reduce the chances of SSMS setup requiring a reboot at the end of installation:

- Make sure you are running an up-to-date version of the Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package. Version 12.00.40649.5 (or greater) is required. Only the x64 version is needed.
- Verify the version of .NET Framework on the computer is 4.6.1 (or
  greater).
- Close any other instances of Visual Studio that are open on the
  computer.
- Make sure all the latest OS updates are installed on the computer.
- The noted actions are typically required only once. There are few
  cases where a reboot is required during additional upgrades to the
  same major version of SSMS. For minor upgrades, all the
  prerequirements for SSMS are already be installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it may worthwhile to match the SSMS update with the SQL Server patching window unless you require it quite frequently.

---

A restart shouldn't be required unless the updated binaries were in use, but you *may* find that next time you want to patch SSMS or SQL Server that it tells you to do a restart before you can start the install process. Whether or not this is an issue is up to you. You may get stuck further down the line with a 'pending reboot'.  My guidance is to always reboot after installing/patching something on a server.  Plan for it and you won't run into this in the future :)